# Encode/decode VP8 or VP9 with Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to find a way to use VP8 or VP9 compressed video, a part of [Googles WebM project](http://www.webmproject.org/) with Gstreamer.

Is there a already a module that can handle VP8? If so, can I get some simple example of how to use it in a broadcast/receive over RTP?

So far there is nothing on the [Gstreamer official documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html). They have Matroska support but that seems only be for demuxing the container.

**Edit** 
There obviously are ways

Server:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480 ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=9001 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2990747501, clock-base=(uint)275641083, seqnum-base=(uint)34810" ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! Autovideosink
```

But the latency is higher than I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes VP8 is already supported.. 
VP9 is missing de/payloader more to that below (not really - gst 1.8 added support - details at bottom)

They are contained in vpx module.
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-vpx.html

VP8:
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-vp8enc.html

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-vp8dec.html

check with `gst-inspect-1.0 vp8enc` if you have it

For RTP you can use webmmux, rtpvp8depay, rtpvp8pay, vp8enc/dec etc..

However, as Burak Arslan stated pay/depayloader for RTP are not ready for now (not even in 1.6.1 I checked)

For the examples - post some pipe with that and we can check it when its not working :)

**EDIT**

[GStreamer 1.8](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/1.8/) was released with support for VP9 - new elements  rtpvp9pay/rtpvp9depay added

Comment: This 
`gst-launch-0.10 -v v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480 ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001`

And this
`gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=9001 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2990747501, clock-base=(uint)275641083, seqnum-base=(uint)34810" ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! Autovideosink`
Is what is currently running. It works ok, but the latency from the webcam is suprisingly high.

Comment: @EinarSundgren: ok, this is for another question.. the main thing is that its working, the latency is another problem

Comment: VP9 over RTP is NOT supported yet. See here for the progress of rtpvp9pay/depay support: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754773